# Merge parent and a child document in to one single doc

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

Is it possible to combine a parent document and a child document of the same parent in to a single doc with fields from both documents using either reindex or scripting?

For example, let's say parent document have fields A,B,C,D and child documents have fields D,E,F,G,H. I want every parent-child pair to be a single doc with fields A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H. If there are 3 children for a single parent, i need three documents where each document has child plus parent fields.

I know it's possible to do it using an external client. Wanted to know if this can be done with in the cluster.

Comment: You can always use nested mapping and put child fields into an inner object in parent dac mapping

Comment: Yes, the problem here is that the all the docs in the existing mapping uses parent-child already.

Comment: so, what's the problem with parent child for you?